# Вытаскиваем данные из Json PHP

Tags: php, json

Есть `json`:

```
{
"success":1,
"items":{
    "StatTrak\u2122 USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)": {
        "price":230.38,
        "count":143,
        "updated":1505288906
    },
```

Имею такой запрос.. Как вывести название `"StatTrak\u2122 USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)"`?

`$r = json_decode(file_get_contents("./inc/cache/prices.txt"));`

Comment: Вообще, лучше вы чтобы эта вся лабуда была значением поля `name`, например. Но если вы не можете влиять на структуру вашего `json`-а, то кладите всё что есть в `items` в массив, потом циклом `foreach` проходитесь по нему.

Comment: Как бы мне это сделать ?  Можно пример? Я могу в javascript залить в базу с названием, но мне надо использовать файл чтобы не нагружать сервер.

Comment: `$items = $r->items;` - положили значения в массив. `foreach( $items as $key=>$value){$itemName = $key; echo ($itemName);};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$JSON = <<<'JSON'
    {
        "success":1,
        "items":{
            "StatTrak\u2122 USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)": {
                "price":230.38,
                "count":143,
                "updated":1505288906
            }
        }
    }
JSON;

    $r = json_decode($JSON, true);
    var_dump($r);
```

Выведет:

```
array (size=2)
  'success' => int 1
  'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      'StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)' => 
        array (size=3)
          'price' => float 230.38
          'count' => int 143
          'updated' => int 1505288906
```

Соответственно, перебрать нужные Вам названия можно кодом:

```php
foreach ($r['items'] as $title => $arr) {
    // Здесь в $title будут попадать названия
    // В $arr будет массив с ключами 'price', 'count', 'updated'
}
```

Если же нужно название именно первого элемента, то его можно получить так:

```php
$firstTitle = array_keys($r['items'])[0];
```

Comment: StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™ USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)StatTrak™  

Запросов несколько и что-то пошло не так

Comment: $JSON = file_get_contents('./inc/cache/prices.txt');

    $r = json_decode($JSON, true);
     $a = 0;
    foreach ($r['items'] as $title => $arr) {

    echo $title = array_keys($r['items'])[$a++];
 }

Comment: @russselo, внутри foreach достаточно `echo $title`